# Problems with ddev after upgrade to 1.21.6 - launch-file empty

Tags: ddev

After updating my ddev to v. 1.21.6 I can't start my projects anmyore.

I get this error:

Failed to run launch ; error=fork/exec /path/to/my/project/.ddev/.global_commands/host/launch: exec format error

When I inspect the file, it's empty (hence the error).

How do I make this run again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Are you out of disk space? Check that. If DDEV tried to create the "launch" custom command and failed it could be an empty file for that reason.
2. Remove your project .ddev/.global_commands directory, `rm -r .ddev/.global_commands`
3. But the likely source of the problem is your global commamnds have been corrupted. They're in `~/.ddev/commands`. You can see if there are some empty ones with `ls -lR ~/.ddev/commands`. If you haven't done any customization to them, remove them all, `rm -r ~/.ddev/commands` and then `ddev restart`

I'd be interested in what you think might have caused this to happen.

One thing though: `ddev launch` is just a helper command. All it does is open your browser to the URL of your project. You can easily just visit the URL of your project in your browser, either by clicking or copying the URL given on `ddev start` or by getting it from `ddev describe`. You don't actually need `ddev launch`.

Comment: The last one did the trick... Thanks a ton!

Comment: I opened https://github.com/ddev/ddev/pull/4775 to hopefully mostly prevent this situation.